# How to give specific class name to category in wordpress with code snippets

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, code

This is my first question here,

all I want is a code snippet where I can give a proper class name to my category
for example

category name: movie
result: category_movie

with code snippets

Comment: An HTML class? For what element?

Comment: HTML class name to menu items

Comment: You don’t need code you can add classes to menu items through the UI. Just check Screen Options to check that the field is enabled.